# ¿Como puedo cambiar el contenido del texto al presionarlo en HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Bueno, resulta que puse un texto que dice "apagado" de color rojo, y que cuando se pasa el puntero encima este diga "encender" en amarillo. Sin embargo mi pregunta es: ¿que hago para que al presionar el texto de "apagado" este cambie a "encendido" en color verde y se quede así fijo hasta que yo vuelva a presionar para apagarlo? Ya intente con el proceso con el que se hacen los botones pero resulta ser distinto, también intente con otro hover pero no funciono (no se muy bien como funcione).
Cabe resaltar que todo va dentro de una tabla:

```css
.contenido .tabla-contenido table {
 position: static;
 margin-top: 30px;
 color: black;
 font-size: 15px;
 border-radius: 8px;
}
.contenido .tabla-contenido table p:before {
 content: "APAGADO";
 color: #c1877a;
}
.contenido .tabla-contenido table p:hover:before {
 content: "ENCENDER";
 color: #f4d742;
 transition: color 0.1s linear 0.1s;
}
```

```html
  <html>
    <section class="contenido">
    <div class="tabla-contenido">
  <center>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>APARATO</td>
     <td>ENCENDIDO/APAGADO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>LAMPARA</td>
     <td><a href="#"><p class="APAGADO"></p></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>LUCES</td>
     <td><a href="#"><p class="APAGADO"></p></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>TV</td>
     <td><a href="#"><p class="APAGADO"></p></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>VENTILADOR</td>
     <td><a href="#"><p class="APAGADO"></p></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>EQUIPO DE SONIDO</td>
     <td><a href="#"><p class="APAGADO"></p></a></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </center>
  </div>
    </section>
    </html>
```

Comment: Solo con CSS no podrás hacerlo, podrías usar `:focus` pero tampoco es permanente. Necesitas javascript.

Comment: Y ahora, como puedo quitar la linea debajo del enlace sin perder el efecto? puesto que uso `text-decoration:none;` y deja de funcionar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto no lo puedes realizar solamente con CSS. Necesitarías algo de `Javascript` para poder hacer el efecto que quieres.

Para este caso, he añadido una nueva clase para los párrafos llamada `pulsado`, en la cual añadiré el texto ENCENDIDO en color verde.

Lo único que hago es asociar un evento para cada uno de los elementos con la clase `APAGADO`, en este caso, que cuando le den click a cualquiera de los elementos que tengan dicha clase se ejecute la función `cambiaLink`.

Por último, dentro de la función, detecto que si el elemento tiene la clase `pulsado` en el momento de hacer click, le quite esa clase, o en caso contrario, se la ponga.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('APAGADO');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click',cambiaLink);
}

function cambiaLink(){
  if(!this.classList.contains("pulsado")){
    this.classList.add("pulsado");
  }else{
    this.classList.remove("pulsado");
  }
    
}
```

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

.contenido .tabla-contenido table {
 position: static;
 margin-top: 30px;
 color: black;
 font-size: 15px;
 border-radius: 8px;
}
.contenido .tabla-contenido table p:before {
 content: "APAGADO";
 color: #c1877a;
}
.contenido .tabla-contenido table p:hover:before {
 content: "ENCENDER";
 color: #f4d742;
 transition: color 0.1s linear 0.1s;
}

.contenido .tabla-contenido table p.pulsado:before{
  content: "ENCENDIDO";
  color: #42f462;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <section class="contenido">
    <div class="tabla-contenido">
 <center>
    <table>
       <tr>
   <td>APARATO</td>
   <td>ENCENDIDO/APAGADO</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>LAMPARA</td>
          <td><a href="#"><p class="APAGADO"></p></a></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>LUCES</td>
          <td><a href="#"><p class="APAGADO"></p></a></td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>TV</td>
          <td><a href="#"><p class="APAGADO"></p></a></td>
              </tr>
       <tr>
   <td>VENTILADOR</td>
   <td><a href="#"><p class="APAGADO"></p></a></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>EQUIPO DE SONIDO</td>
   <td><a href="#"><p class="APAGADO"></p></a></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
 </center>
    </div>
    </section>
</html>
```

Comment: excelente, es mi impresion, o ere brujo, respondes muy rapido, bien por eso :D

Comment: Excelente jaj, gracias amigo, me fuiste de mucha ayuda,,,

Comment: Y ahora, como puedo quitar la linea debajo del enlace sin perder el efecto? puesto que uso `text-decoration:none;` y deja de funcionar

Comment: @e2vl13 ¿Dónde se lo estabas aplicando? El `text-decoration: none` se lo tienes que aplicar a los links (a los elementos `a`). He editado mi respuesta para que veas el resultado.

Comment: Okay, gracias, lo estaba aplicando para `table`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Apagado</button>
<script>
function myFunction(){
  var x=document.getElementById("myBtn");
  if(x.innerHTML==="Encendido"){
    x.innerHTML="Apagado";
    x.style.backgroundColor="#EFEFEF";
  }
  else{
    x.innerHTML="Encendido";
  x.style.backgroundColor="#18ff00";}}</script>
```

Comment: Una explicación además del código siempre se agradece